# EXCEL - Extracting specific numbers

Tags: excel

can you please advise me, how can I extract only some numbers from cell to another cell via function? I have some numbers in one cell:

```
00001 70043383 01.04.2015.
```

I want to extract to another cell only **70043383** , because I extracted date **01.04.2015** via function =LEFT(A2, 10) but I can not do the same from right side because I do not want numbers **00001** .

Thank you.

Comment: me thinks you have your left and right reversed. look into the mid() function. `=MID(A2,6,8)`

Comment: You could separate all three sets of numbers by using Text to Columns.  Use a 'space' as your delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

To do this as a function (as opposed to a Text To Columns action), then assuming your numbers are delimited by spaces:

```
=VALUE(MID(A1, FIND(" ", A1), FIND(" ", A1, FIND(" ", A1) + 1) - FIND(" ", A1)))
```

To explain:

- `FIND(" ", A1)` will find the first space for us;
- `FIND(" ", A1, FIND(" ", A1) + 1)` will find the second space for us;
- `MID` will extract the text;
- `VALUE` will convert it to a number.